# Why are SocketChannels abstract?

Tags: java, class, sockets, oop, nio

I'm writing a socket server based on NIO.

I thought it would be a smart idea to create a class that extends NIO's `SocketChannel` class so that I can store custom information directly in the socket object.

This would be easy with the `java.net.Socket`:

```
public class Session extends Socket {
    private Long created = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

But I can't do anything like that with `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` because it's an abstract class. If I want to extends `SocketChannel`, I would need to write a bunch of methods.

As far as I know, abstract classes cannot be instanciated so methods like `ServerSocketChannel.accept()` must actually return a concrete class that extends `SocketChannel`. If so, what is the class called? If not, why is the class abstract at all?

Comment: There are different concrete implementations that you don't need to concern yourself with. Your example with `Socket` would also be bad design. Prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: The way to handle a session in NIO is to make it the attachment of the SelectionKey.

Comment: Many people would consider it a *good thing* that `public class Session extends Socket {private Long created = System.currentTimeMillis();}` doesn't work for SocketChannels (or for any other class) and a bad thing that it works for Sockets.

Comment: @immibis That might be true. My question was why it doesn't work. I wanted to understand the mechanism behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's the case. The Javadoc doesn't say anything about the concrete class that is actually instanciated, then it must be private or package private so it is not visible from the outside. The first thing that comes to mind is that the implementation is platform specific (calling the particular OSes primitives through JNI) but does not add any extra method. It's only an hypothesis, I never saw the source code.

However you can easily extend the class through inheritance and composition. Your implementations will simply forward calls to the methods to the concrete object you hold as private member within your derived class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where you would use the decorator pattern instead.

```
public class Session{

    private SelectableChannel channel;
    private Long created = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public Session(SelectableChannel channel){
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public <T>T getChannel(){
        return (T)channel;
    }

    public long getWhenCreated(){
        return created;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this.

```
Session session = new Session(DatagramChannel.open());
Session session2 = new Session(SocketChannel.open());

DatagramChannel datagramChannel = session.getChannel();
SocketChannel socketChannel = session2.getChannel();
```

Comment: Why do you use generics with the `getChannel` method?

Comment: @JohannBauer because, otherwise you would have to say `DatagramChannel datagramChannel = (DatagramChannel) session.getChannel();`. Unnecessary casting is annoying.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great example. But the other answer actually answered the original question so I accepted that one.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is create a wrapper class that takes the SocketChannel in the constructor and delegates to it for all method calls. You will need to implement all the methods of SocketChannel but you would just delegate those calls to SocketChannel and add any additional functionality you need before or after those calls.